# Partially extracting a zip file from a network share

Tags: c++, zip, zlib

Is it possible to extract a single file from a zip file located in a network share, without downloading the entire file and therefore avoid loading it completely in memory?

Any idea of a cross-platform library that can do it?

Comment: "Is it possible?" - Yes. Basic procedure is simple: `Seek` to near the end of the ZIP file and find the "End of central directory record (EOCD)". The EOCD tells you where in the file the "Central directory" starts, so you `seek` to its position and process the directory until you find the file you're looking for. The directory entry then tells you where in the ZIP file your file of interest begins, so you `seek` to there and can decompress the single file. The amount of unneeded data to read is very low (directory entries only). However, I don't know any (C++) library to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) or [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) can do that.  The zip format is designed to support that, with a central directory at the end that points to the individual entries in the zip file, each separately decompressible.